# how to rewrite simple multicolumn command for use with new tabularray interface?

Tags: multicolumn, tabularray

Long time ago I defined some templates. In one of them I used this

```
\newcommand{\zwiueb}[1]{%
   \multicolumn{3}{l}{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{#1}}}%
}
```

which obviously does no longer work with tabularray.

I have not yet succeeded in rewriting this rather simple command such that it works for the new tabularray interface.

All it should do is, set some text across all three columns in a `longtblr` environment.

Edit:

here is my minimal (not) working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcommand{\zwiueb}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{%
    rowsep=1.1pt,%
    width = \linewidth,%
    colspec = {r>{\raggedright\sffamily\footnotesize}XX[3.3]}%
    }
first col & second col & third col \\
\zwiueb{span all three cols}\\
first col & second col & third col \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

yields this error:

```
! Misplaced \omit. \multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan  l.20 \end
       {longtblr}
```

---

Next try after getting the first comments:

```
\newcommand{\zwiueb}[1]{%
  \SetCell[c=3]{l, font=\bfseries}{#1}
}
```

result is this:

[image]

---

just to clearify: this is what I'd like to see:

[image]

working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}[=v2021]

\newcommand{\zwiueb}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{%
    rowsep=1.1pt,%
    width = \linewidth,%
    colspec = {r>{\raggedright\sffamily\footnotesize}XX[3.3]}%
    }
first col & second col & third col \\
\zwiueb{span all three columns to make sort of a heading} \\
first col & second col & third col \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

but I'd like to get the same result without the need of `[=v2021]`

Comment: I thought the new interface just change how a table is set up, not how the contents are filled in.  Could you post a minimal example that you think should work but doesn't, along with its error?

Comment: `\SetCell[c=3]{l, font=\bfseries}    text in cell` or  `\SetCell[c=3]{l}    \textbf{text in cell}`  or in case that whole ros has boldface texr, use `row{<number>{ = {font=\bfseries}`. See package documentation of recent `tabularray` version  (2022B, 2022C, etc). Be aware, that new syntax require that in row should be all ampersands as are specified columns, For an example see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672335/columns-in-table-not-expanding-as-expected/672341#672341.

Comment: Sww package documentation; **6.2 The History** where is described  work around:`\usepackage{tabularray}[=v2021]`  if you like to use old way for writting of multicolumn cells. But , be aware that new nice option as is `guar` for use of text in`S` columns` is not available and you had to stick with `{{{ ...}}}`, also new libraries like `functional` , `zref` ...

Comment: I would like to adapt my template to the new interface, but it dosen't work like expected ...

`\newcommand{\zwiueb}[1]{
  \SetCell[c=3]{l, font=\bfseries}{#1}
}`
results in neither bf font nor text across all three columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, if this is what you after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
% new command instead of \zwiueb, 
% with optional number of spanned columns
% you can use old name, but better is replace it b
\NewTableCommand\SCC[1]{\SetCell[c=#1]{c, font=\bfseries}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[% here shoulb caption, label, note{...}, remark{...}
                    ]{rowsep  = 1.1pt,
                      colspec = {r X[l, font=\sffamily\footnotesize] X[3.3, l]},
                      vlines  % only for test purposesm remove in your document
                }
first col   & second col    & third col \\
\SCC{3} span all three cols             % instead of \zwiueb{span all three cols}
            &     a          &   b      \\
first col   & second col    & third col \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That one sort of did the trick.

Comment: great!

works as expected now:

`\NewTableCommand\zwiueb{\SetCell[c=3]{l, font=\bfseries}}`

and I don't have to change my documents, still using

`\zwiueb{ new test --- span all three columns to make sort of a heading} \\  `

Thanks @Zarko

Answer (score 0):

For reference: this is how the minimal example finally looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewTableCommand\zwiueb{\SetCell[c=3]{l, font=\bfseries}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{%
    rowsep=1.1pt,%
    width = \linewidth,%
    colspec = {r>{\raggedright\sffamily\footnotesize}XX[3.3]}%
    }
first col & second col & third col \\
\zwiueb{ new test --- span all three columns to make sort of a heading} \\
first col & second col & third col \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

with this result:

[image]